# Suppressing incoming ringtone like FaceTime Video

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer

FaceTime manages to play a different ringtone on an incoming, interrupting ("normal" / SIM based) voice call during a FaceTime Video session. This ringtone is less intrusive. Furthermore it manages to continue streaming the audio, while it pauses the Video stream.

E.g. if I try the same on WhatsApp, WhatsApp simply pauses the the whole call as soon as the incoming call appears. It also plays the standard ringtone.

My use case is playback of short audio clips to the user (< 10 sec), in some cases the user may only be able to listen to 1 single time. So it would be nice if this clip could be played without being interrupted.
I managed to do that on Android, during the playback an incoming call will only show a small Toast like system message where the call can be accepted or declined. The ringtone is also turned off for that short duration. FaceTime is the best counterpart of iOS behavior that i could find.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to play sounds uninterrupted by certain apps / calls.

`AVAudioSession` has the `setCategory:` method that allows you change the type of audio your app (session) is playing.

```swift
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

Set your audio session to active and set the appropriate category for the audio you want to play. According to the table (*Audio Session category behavior*) in the link below, and if I understand correctly, `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` is the appropriate category for you to set.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html